# Switch Statement C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, switch-statement

Can someone please tell me why my switch statement is not working? In my program I have a text box with the choices of 'Billing', 'Tech Support', 'Retention', 'Customer Service'. My switch statement is saying if that text box is = xxx then show a form I build and hide everything else.

Currently only the billing and other option works?!

<

```
private void cbDept_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string reason = cbDept.Text;

            switch (reason)
            {
                case "Billing":
                    gbBilling.Show();
                    gbTechSupport.Hide();
                    gbCS.Hide();
                    gbRetention.Hide();
                    lbOtherReason.Hide();
                    txtOther.Hide();
                    break;
                case "Tech Support":
                    gbTechSupport.Show();
                    gbBilling.Hide();
                    gbCS.Hide();
                    gbRetention.Hide();
                    lbOtherReason.Hide();
                    txtOther.Hide();
                    break;
                case "Retention":
                    gbRetention.Show();
                    gbBilling.Hide();
                    gbTechSupport.Hide();
                    gbCS.Hide();
                    lbOtherReason.Hide();
                    txtOther.Hide();
                    break;
                case "Customer Service":
                    gbCS.Show();
                    gbBilling.Hide();
                    gbTechSupport.Hide();
                    gbRetention.Hide();
                    lbOtherReason.Hide();
                    txtOther.Hide();
                    break;
                case "Other":
                    txtOther.Show();
                    lbOtherReason.Show();
                    gbCS.Hide();
                    gbBilling.Hide();
                    gbTechSupport.Hide();
                    gbRetention.Hide();
                    break;
                default:
                    gbCS.Hide();
                    gbBilling.Hide();
                    gbTechSupport.Hide();
                    gbRetention.Hide();
                    break;
            }

        }
```

>

Comment: Don't use the `Text` property of the combobox, use it's `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` property instead.

Comment: have you inspected with the debugger?

Comment: No I haven't. Sort of new at this so I'll try that when I get home and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is some misspelling in the other options. Check the values of reason before reaching the switch.

Comment: due to issues like these it is always advisable to have either an enum or string constants declared.